# FileMaker Script Step "Pause" is not Supported on the FM 11 Server. Is there a workaround?

Tags: database, relational-database, filemaker

I'm attempting to include a Pause step within a script that will run nightly on our FileMaker 11 server.

Here's the code that I would like to execute:

```
Loop
    Pause/Resume Script [Duration (seconds): 0.01]
    <do something and exit based on some condition>
End Loop
```

The pause needs to be approximately 1/100 seconds.

The roadblock is that the `Pause/Resume Script` is not supported by FileMaker Server, but rather only by the Client application.

I've already considered using `Get(CurrentHostTimestamp)`, and continuing with the loop after 0.01 seconds have passed. However, this will not work because `Get(CurrentHostTimestamp)` only provides an accuracy of 1 second. I've also considered including a loop that will perform a meaningless calculation with the side-effect of causing a delay. But this would not be precise and seems like a waste of computing cycles.

Is there a workaround apart from running this script on a client rather than the server?

I'll include some detail about what I've tried.

`Get(CurrentTimeUTCMilliseconds)` would allow me to get a more accurate timestamp, but this is only supported starting in v 13.

```
Loop 
    Set Variable [ $time ; Value: Get ( CurrentTimeUTCMilliseconds ) ]
       Loop
    Exit Loop If [ (Get ( CurrentTimeUTCMilliseconds ) - $time) > 1000 ] 
    End Loop
    <do something and exit based on some condition> 
End Loop
```

I'd like to avoid plugins because they may not be compatible with future versions. However, I've considered this plugin from MBS: [Time.Sleep](https://www.mbsplugins.eu/TimeSleep.shtml)

Comment: Adding a Pause into a program, other than to display something to a user, is frequently not a reliable way to achieve a goal because there's often no way to know whether the thing you've been waiting for is completed yet. What is this pause waiting for? Is there a way to test for completion, instead?

Comment: While @pft221 is correct that pausing to wait for something is usually served by some better algorithm, it may be that the pause isn't required at all. How long does the test for the exit condition take? If it takes on the order of 0.01 seconds, then you might be able to leave the `Pause/Resume Script` step out. If you really do require a pause for 1/100th second, check out `BE_CurrentTimeMilliseconds` from the BaseElements plugin (http://www.goya.com.au/baseelements/plugin).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've added some more details above. I'm considering asking a separate question about how to validate completion of the condition that I'm waiting for during the pause. I think that deserves a separate question.